# Where can I deploy firebase cloud functions project rather than google?

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-functions

Unfortunately I can't deploy my project to google because there is problem with credit card. Which hosting provider can I use to deploy my firebase cloud functions project?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions is a customized system built by Google for use in Google Cloud.  It's not a standard that's supported by other cloud providers, so you can't deploy that code exactly as it is to other clouds.  You can certainly reuse your business logic anywhere, but you will have to adapt it to different infrastructure.

If you want to build a portable backend, consider learning Docker, as you can build images that could be deployed to many different cloud providers.